# javascript onmouseover and onmouseout issue

Tags: javascript, dom, onmouseover, background-position, onmouseout

Ok I have a javascript rollover. I want the clicked3 picture to be selected in the beginning and when I rollover it or rollover the other pictures the clicked3 would be deselected. The picture ids in my html are: clicked1,clicked2,clicked3,clicked4. I've done this code but it doesn't work. It seems that the picture1 rollover is not working and picture3 is not starting selected... any help?

```
window.onload=function() {
    var domClicked1=document.getElementById("clicked1");
    var domClicked2=document.getElementById("clicked2");
    var domClicked3=document.getElementById("clicked3");
    var domClicked3=document.getElementById("clicked4");

    clicked1.call(domClicked1);
    clicked2.call(domClicked2);
    clicked3.call(domClicked3);
    clicked4.call(domClicked4);

    domClicked1.onmouseover=handleOver1;
    domClicked2.onmouseover=handleOver2;
    domClicked3.onmouseover=handleOver3;
    domClicked3.onmouseover=handleOver4; 


    domClicked1.onmouseout=handleOut1;
    domClicked2.onmouseout=handleOut2;
    domClicked3.onmouseout=handleOut3;
    domClicked4.onmouseout=handleOut4;

}

function clicked1(){
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "0px top";
}

function handleOver1() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "-198px top";
}

function handleOut1() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "-198px top";
}



function clicked3(){
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "-198px top";
}

function handleOver3() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "-198px top";
}

function handleOut3() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "0px top";
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you do not use jQuery for this?

Comment: cause the agent i work for wants it this way.. any help?

Comment: I think you should convince your agent that this is just a bad idea.

Comment: I tried.. If you have an answer though would be good.. I think I will use a jquery but don't think he's going to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to make it work!!!

```
window.onload=function() {
var domClicked1=document.getElementById("clicked1");
var domClicked2=document.getElementById("clicked2");
var domClicked3=document.getElementById("clicked3");
var domClicked4=document.getElementById("clicked4");



clicked3.call(domClicked3);

domClicked1.onmouseover=handleOver1;
domClicked1.onmouseout=handleOut1;

domClicked2.onmouseover=handleOver2;
domClicked2.onmouseout=handleOut2;

domClicked3.onmouseover=handleOver3; 
domClicked3.onmouseout=handleOut3;

domClicked4.onmouseover=handleOver4;
domClicked4.onmouseout=handleOut4;
```

}

```
function handleOver1(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}

function handleOut1(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}

function handleOver2(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}

function handleOut2(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}



function clicked3(){
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "-198px top";
}

function handleOver3() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "-198px top";
}

function handleOut3() {
    this.style.backgroundPosition = "0px top";
}

function handleOver4(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}

function handleOut4(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition="0px top";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove bits of code and solve your issues problem by problem. For example...first try to show picture3 starting selected...and than start coding further from there.

Comment: well the picture3 is selected and works with if put:                                       window.onload=function(){
clicked3();
}

function clicked3(){
document.getElementById("clicked3").style.backgroundPosition = "-198px top";
}

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you should use only one event listener for all your elements. Give the event listener to the parent containing your elements and refer to the one being clicked using `e.target`. Use one event listener for the mouse over, one for the mouse out, and one for the click. This will save resources.

Then, instead of changing CSS properties on the fly, set a CSS rule for a given class name and add/remove only that class with JavaScript.

Additionally, when you change the background coordinated with CSS, you should always use the same method, for example if you use pixels on one coordinate, use pixels also for the other one, like `"-198px 0"` instead of `"-198px top"`.